# unable to create key file. ubuntu installation error

Tags: ubuntu, preseed

I am trying to generate a preseed file for automating the Ubuntu installation process.
I want full disk encryption with the help of preseed having the pass-phrase included in the preseed.

I wrote this:

```
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase password helloworld
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase-again password helloworld
```

it is giving me error:

```
unable to generate key file.
```

I have tried many links but none helped:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/24079/full-disk-encryption-with-preseed
https://askubuntu.com/questions/305176/preseed-with-lvm-and-crypto-fails-with-an-error-occured-while-creating-the-keyf?rq=1

but every time I got the same error.

The thing is when I do it without the help of any preseed everything works fine.
I want to know how to write a preseed for full disk encryption.
I also referred to [Ubuntu documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Enterprise/WorkstationAutoinstallPreseed),  but that also did not help. 
And this guide is not having much information for writing a preseed for encryption

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the full error output verbatim.

Comment: error is simple a dialog box saying unable to create key file. and when i click on the ok button on the dialog box and i will be directed to partition manager

Comment: @Networker what is a 'pressed' file? The original 'preseed' I could understand.

Comment: @Anthon,sorry I didn't know about 'preseed' file before

Comment: @Networker So what does pressed mean in this context? Preseed -> Pre-seed -> fill up before hand?

Comment: @Anthon, I just auto correct it, sorry again I will be more careful in the future

Comment: @Networker Please be more careful with your edits. There is enough in this post that could have been improved without the use of autocorrect ( "but it also did not helped" e.g.).

Comment: i am not that good at english. but anyhow i can deliver my message.. sorry for that.. is there any suggestions regarding the problem